# Passing optional object Type in Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

> I created a Module for Event Hub I want to make dimension block optional based on
> dimeval variable of object type.I am trying to do if i pass the value to the
> dimension block will be initialized if i don't pass the values
> dimension block should be avoided

> Module main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "EhAlert" {
          for_each = var.alert_rules
      
  name                = each.value.alertname
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  description         = each.value.description
  scopes              = var.alert_scope
  severity            = each.value.severity
  frequency           = each.value.frequency
  window_size         = each.value.windowsize
  criteria {
    metric_namespace  = each.value.metric_namespace
    threshold         = each.value.threshold
    metric_name       = each.value.metric_name
    aggregation       = each.value.aggregation
    operator          = each.value.operator
    
 
    dynamic "dimension" {
      for_each = each.value.dimeval == null ?  [] : [1]
      content{
      name     = each.value.dimeval["name"]
      operator = each.value.dimeval["operater"]
      values   = each.value.dimeval["values"]
      }
    }
    }
        action {
         action_group_id = var.actiongroupid
       }
  }
```

> module variable.tf

```
variable "alert_rules" {
  type = map(object({  
     alertname = string 
     metric_namespace = string      
     severity = number
     metric_name = string
     frequency = any
     windowsize = any
     aggregation = string
     description = string
     operator = string
     threshold = number       
     dimeval = map(object({
        name    = string
        operater = any
       values = list(string)
      }))
       
  }))
```

> Root module variable.tf .In this var file i passed empty by expecting to avoid the
> dimension block without passing values but it is showing this error
> each.value.dimeval is empty map of object

```
variable "alert_rulesEH" {
    type = map(object({  
     alertname = string 
     metric_namespace = string      
     severity = number
     metric_name = string
     frequency = any
     windowsize = any

     aggregation = string
     dimeval = map(object({
        name    = string
        operater = any
       values = list(string)
      }))
     description = string
     operator = string
     threshold = number        
    }))


     default = {

     
    Alert_0 = {
    alertname = "Connections Opened to eventhub"
    severity = 2
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces"
    metric_name = "IncomingRequests"
    frequency = "PT30M"
    windowsize = "PT1H"
    description = "Connections openedmore than 200"
    aggregation = "Total"
    operator = "GreaterThan"
    threshold = 200
    dimeval = {}
    # dimeval = {
    #     name    = "EntityName"
    #     operater = "Include"
    #    values = ["eventhub"]
    #   }
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: Did you see an error when you tried to apply this configuration? Can you edit your question to include the error, or alternatively to include the behavior you observed and how that differed from what you intended?

Comment: It is showing this error >> each.value.dimeval is empty map of object <<.beacuse i didnt passed any value to the object type variable.Even if i pass null it is asking me to enter values for each object type values( string, any , list(string) ).The reason why i didnt passed is i want to get null value in order to avoid dimension block execution

Answer (score 0):

- I tried to reproduce scenario to set monitoring alerts to my storage
  accounts and not to include any dimensions as it is optional.
- Even I tried to mention the dimensions block , with no values and got
  error that argument is missing or say its values like name are
  needed.

something like below for my scenario:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
  name                = "<metric alert name>"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_storage_account.example.id]
  description         = ".... greater than 50."

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    metric_name      = "<metric name>"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "<like GreaterThan>"
    threshold        = 52

     dimension {
       #no value

    }
action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.main.id
  }
}
      }
```

---

[image]

---

***So I tried to remove the dimension block itself and run the code, it successfully run without errors and created an metric alert :***

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
  name                = "<metric alert name>"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_storage_account.example.id]
  description         = ".... greater than 50."


  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    metric_name      = "Transactions"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 50

    

 action {
action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.main.id
           }
       }
```

---

[image]

---

- ***Metric alert got created successfully for my storage account:***

---

[image]

So if you need not want optional parameter dimension, then please try to remove that dimension block(which is optional) and try.

**Reference**: [azurerm_monitor_metric_alert | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert)

Comment: My issue was solved.the catch is if u declaring dimension block we have to provide values in it.other wise we can make it optional by using condition like  this **for_each = criteria.value.dimension != null ? criteria.value.dimension : [].**